# Making some elements on a form invisible with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form with an id of "dialogForm" containing input, textareas and selects.

I would like to make all of the above elements (except the one with id="Text") not visible so that the 
user cannot see or enter any new data in them.

```
<textarea class="mceEditor wijmo-wijtextbox ui-widget 
                         ui-state-default ui-corner-all" name="Text" 
id="Text" style="width: 825px;" rows="10" cols="99">test</textarea>
```

I'd then like to style the above element so it completely fills the form. Can someone give me some pointers as to how I can do this.

Comment: make one wrapper div of all element as exmaple its id is wrapperdiv use jquery like $('#wrapperdiv').not('#text').hide();

Comment: this is not correct. not is kind of filter. so your selector containing only one element `wrapperdiv`. cannot filter. you need to get child elements.

Comment: hmmm.thats right $('#wrapperdiv').children().not('#text').hide();

Comment: and no need to wrap it again, since he is having form tag  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9544728/880434

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal - You cannot guarantee that these elements will be children of the container either, `.find()` would be better suited.

Comment: @GoranMottram: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9544728/880434 he mention about the form tag

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal - I'm not disputing the form tag. I'm disagreeing with the use of [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/). It will only look for the form's immediate children and ignore any elements buried further down within divs, tables or lists. That's why [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) is better suited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide just specific form elements, you'll want something like the following:

```
$('#dialogForm').find('input[type="text"], select, textarea:not(#text)').hide();
```

This will ensure that your `<textarea id="text" />` element along with other elements (divs and such) aren't hidden either. If you need to add other elements like checkboxes and such, just append them to the selector list.

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/Bvndr/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#dialogForm").children().not("#id").css("display":"none");
```